# video editor name of attached screenshot

Tags: video

I'm trying to find out what video editing program does this type of graphical layer to input title over video.

[image: sample video]

Here are several videos edited with this same program but no reference of the video editor used.

[google image search](https://www.google.com/search?tbs=sbi:AMhZZit8OGASlL_1SaDL0kHSq52z9pSIOQOMur7klZpkwqLXs4bR8Gjf7TyQJ5CPYLK7InF4UddI8RZyeBZkrzqdkfvU5YJQlPbRHhBYsNHzRgnU8Q7KieLJmhVaGsf-eDoEQTPq9vmiijEarlyCt3kl7nOea8VaBNN_11321o9GifOJ3qFQu8HXv4VDSS2j5eos96-j6zZiBIVaueOVfVcmXV2L9J0UxnB8ktCx2Q4kbGJ7fcsNAFEygRK2N4LaFqBDM2BIqH7ZYrk1RBD6ZDLS2JmjScH_1p_1SM2zZQYTqthqPL2buHYC1KXDnZuminltcalBOZrUFeB3atl5F2A7ysBiinoEgcVkYC_1Dxw17YOFMxhs_1J-oJ4xwdUgA0m3D3eLnCADPSDwvz54ccAYd5Y4ZbKctP0U5uUcNaAqjP4G726zrc2F1Io_1VAJUzI41Z14m_1Q2TVjgm5d2cHX_1AAohQfLQSiXsrPE2tJHO64Lnm-pZ7YakDka7VyLwnqsgtDcoQj23i762OkM8Hyz-uhHR_1Jeuw0i6yquixXW8GedqZT3UukWW5vuotqgehuAQDDWckNP5ePb81lCMZ0BBnYLTmEf8x68V4Mp5W_1Ve3K1334fDp2jG2fUh9RmBtDgTA8t278YP6d54_1ib9Rtp82K0Hp3dJAPKRJbIUfWotqbiGN6Ac-MTfC0CjD5MXTIXC9y_1ivFsCVIGFGLV8jLk-anqp4VmuGIDuvvhEtLcTk4jjN1Q26bbLVHsHXzUNjSHxmBAOpZSpIUXmNtPyfJoaG23c-kNtpevDQjuVL7W1xEMRUW5rPi8bg1-rPRLbB_1-tvdvJI6Fey2f5inJCdoG8Hwv5l7d3Lyf891O6xiy96tNsjDA9jXqhlWwN_17izDq0V8oSaLbfa4IzNHWaqTHi8ckebSxCA0q_1WoqH3BAVJrxQtMA7Z05XPGBKY8_1z9cFBx3uda9wHyjdutX8w_1kfQ3Q1vk0aXXsoYe6OdAO-3zh2cR2VNx8n0EeyxWI8zwnZSD-rVDuL6i9cnJa4nuUnGpTskwkGsa_1qG96KMmPh6QyPOf-Pj7jYlxCABNlsqWVdtAgXDhrScy3S9JdUlGCWMephntnBNp1lF1YIJn7ojTKQdXx5YkDvQNS18IbGITQ_1XJYXQYm5_1dDL4QByM0Utvl7NwBAo6onQCnnU_1oN-DCwCBYRIrworTcW7Axb9_1183qvJKAbpCmc0dK_15aYAHTQSmNq6t6xh-8rrxK2lTNLRxRGExIpM75Dg-8TK8rfa4Z3DEfiSWnuLQRLu4qePda2ngtyrHoV_1AuB1x5lbA&safe=off&hl=en&bih=1263&biw=1328)

Anybody can help?

`EDIT`:

Because people keep telling it's just some edited image with FX that any editing program can do, here are the effects which keep popping up on youtube, all pixel-perfectly equal:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Sorry, this is not a good question for Stack Exchange sites. See [Let’s Play The Guessing Game](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game/). Also, why are you sure that this one specific program that can do it? Why shouldn't any video effects program be able to generate that? A proper question would be how to achieve such an effect in a program you're already using – maybe not here but on [avp.SE].

Comment: Ok tell me the video effects program prebuilt effect or the available plugin to do that, if you look at the videos you'll realize it's not a photoshop image which everyone just redraws from scratch.

Comment: And by the way, ok it's a guessing game, where should I put this question then?

Comment: Like I said, *"a proper question would be how to achieve such an effect in a program you're already using"* – you simply need to ask for a specific problem you need to solve rather than have people guess who created that effect. It might be better suited for [avp.SE] or [graphicdesign.SE], but please check their scope first.

Comment: @dendini did you read the "[Let's Play The Guessing Game](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game/)" post? Ok, so a specific software is creating this, it still is off topic for this website to just ask "Identify the software that created this".

Comment: If you're the person who asked the poster of http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KmFr_3ubqaY which software they used, that's really the only viable option in that case.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to determine which program was used to create this <strike>image</strike> animation with having only the animation as reference, because there are many choices of how to do it.
But my guess will be Adobe After Effects or something similar.

Comment: It is not so hard if you watch all the videos attached, they all use the same effects so there must be a canned layer in some common video editing program. Of course if you don't know there's no way that from the above image you can find out the editing program and of course you can create the above image with Photoshop or Gimp, but my question is more specific.

Comment: Every software like AfterFX can do this effect with no difference at the final render. No way of knowing the specifics.

Comment: Ok I have De Rerum Natura book in my hand, you don't know the author and so don't I, anybody could have written that copy with any typewriter and no way of knowing who. Of course I'm looking for the author and of course Lucretius wrote it, just I don't have a search engine available for video overlay effects and so I'm asking

Comment: It's not the same. Every writer has his/her own unique style of writing. Software doesn't.

Comment: Ok so all 30 videos from 30 different uploaders who have ages ranging from 10 to 30 just opened AfterFX and started drawing from scratch a video overlay which is pixel-perfectly equal to the screenshot attached? And by the way you'll see in the videos posted several overlays are the same, for instance the green one on the bottom to show text on the movie, or the final blue one on the bottom right.

Comment: You will be able to obtain such result with after effects after 30 mins of learning, trust me. And even if not, there's is still no way to know what software was used. I'm done with this question